# CSS apply style except on :after

Tags: html, css, styles, line-through

From the following CSS code:

```
p {text-decoration: line-through;}
p:after {text-decoration: none;
content:" text";}
```

with HTML:

```
<p>abcd</p>
```

I woud expect the following:
<s>abcd</s> text
However I get this:
<s>abcd text</s>

Why is this and how can I get what I wanted to achieve?

Comment: why you don't use `<del>blue</del>` tag for break line it;s the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `display: inline-block;`

```css
p {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

p:after {
  content: " text";
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>abcd</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to select the after then apply `text-decoration: none`. I.e:

`p:after p { text-decoration: none;  }`